# Python: separating words using space, but preserving double quotes surrounded text as single unit

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string that looks like this:

```
one two three "four five"
```

I'd like to split such that I get an array:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four five']
```

using `split` with `' '` will not be enough here. I have to separate out the double quotes first. Is there a best practice technique to do this? or should I re-invent the wheel and do it myself?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following regex matching:

```
import re

s = 'one two three "four five"'
words = re.findall(r'(\w+|"[^"]+")', s)
print(words)
```

- `(a|b)` - matches either what is before the `|` or what is after it
- `\w+` - match any word
- `"[^"]+"` - match any sequence of characters except `"` which is surrounded by quotes

---

```
['one', 'two', 'three', '"four five"']
```

Answer (score 3):

With "*should I re-invent the wheel and do it myself?*" as primary requirement we can reuse something meant for something else

```
import csv
import io
s='one two three "four five"'
f=csv.reader(io.StringIO(s),dialect="excel",delimiter=" ")
for i in f:
    print(i)

['one', 'two', 'three', 'four five']
```